# DiagrammeR fontsize argument does nothing

Tags: r, diagrammer

I can change the fontsize argument below to be either `graph [fontsize = 1]` or `graph [fontsize = 10]` or `graph [fontsize = 100]` and the output in my R Studio viewer is identical. It appears the font defaults to a reasonable size that fills the node it occupies. How do I change the font size?

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("
  digraph test {
    graph [fontsize = 10]

    node [shape = box]
    A [label = 'FooBar']
    B [label = 'BarFoo']

    A -> B
  }
")
```

Comment: add the fontsize to the `node` declaration

Comment: @user20650 do you want to put that as the answer and I'll mark it solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change the font size of the node labels within the node declaration.

You can change it using `node`: `node [shape = box, fontsize=5]` or in a specific node label with: `A [label = 'FooBar', fontsize=5]`